# How to properly configure requireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, single-page-application, amd

Hi I'm trying to make starting template for SPA project mainly using:
RequireJS, KnockoutJS, TypeScript, etc.

I'm having hard time figuring out how to configure paths and folder structure for RequireJS to work properly...

here is my folder structure:

```
Scripts
 app
  components
   main.js
 lib
  knockout.js
  jquery.js
```

here is my RequireJS config file:

```
var config = {
    waitSeconds: 15,        
    paths: {
        app: '../app',
        'knockout': '/lib/knockout-3.4.2.',
        sammy: '/lib/sammy-0.7.5.',
        jquery: '../scripts/lib/jquery-1.10.2.'
    }
};
```

This is my attempt for main.js:

```
define(['jquery', 'PageOne', 'PageTwo'], function ($, pageOne, pageTwo) {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var app = Sammy('#main', function () {

            this.get('#/pageOne', function () {
                pageOne.activate();
            });

            this.get('#/pageTwo', function () {
                pageTwo.activate();
            });

        });
        app.run();
    });
});
```

Here is my Index.cshtml script tag:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/lib/require.js" data-main="scripts/app/components/main"></script>
```

I saw in different project that config is called in header so this is in html header:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/app/config/require.config.js"></script>
```

My problem is that in main.js it looks for jquery under path defined in data-main (scripts/app/components/), but my jquery is in scripts/lib folder.

I'm trying to figure out by reading online the whole day but it's too much time for me I need someone to give me some hints how is this supposed to work?

Seriously having hard time figuring this out and RequireJS website just isn't helping me atm.

> Note: I am beginner in JavaScript based projects, first SPA attempt,
>   never used RequireJS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration file does not do anything. I'm assuming from your description that the `script` element that loads it is located before the `script` element that loads RequireJS. That's one valid way to configure RequireJS, but if you want RequireJS to pick up the configuration, **you need to set the global variable `require`** before you load RequireJS, and RequireJS will use the value of `require` as its configuration. Right now you are setting `config`, which is ignored by RequireJS. So:

```
var require = {
    waitSeconds: 15,    
    // etc...
```

And once the configuration is in effect, you should be able to reduce your `data-main` to `data-main="components/main"`.

I see some of your paths in the `paths` configuration end with a dot. That's most likely a mistake on your part, or you have some very strange file names.

Comment: I thought that the variable is up to me to name, I had it set on var require as an example I was looking at before but for some reason it  started to give me some error (in some requirejs file) and I couldn't build so I renamed it to config thinking it doesn't matter... Yes the dot part is my mistake again lol... I'm gonna give it a second try. Thanks for the hints...

Comment: I renamed the var into var require and I get this error: "Variable 'require' must be of type '{ waitSeconds: number; paths: { app: string; knockout: string; sammy: string; jquery: string; }; ...', but here has type 'Require'."

Comment: Do you have any idea what gives this error message? I don't see anything in RequireJS' source code that would give this error. (Besides, there'd be no reason for it.) Is this happening at run time? Is this happening when you build your project? (You mentioned TypeScript so I assume you have some build steps.)

Comment: Hi, apparently this error is coming from require.d.ts file which is requirejs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped library for require... so I guess it's a TypeScript bug I'm looking for some solutions online and it's only some hacks lol

Comment: Are you processing the file that holds your RequireJS configuration with TypeScript? If so, then maybe setting the configuration with `var require: Require = {...} as any` would satisfy TypeScript. It is a bit of a cheat though. Otherwise, you may need to exclude your RequireJS configuration file from being processed with TypeScript.

Comment: I wrote it like this: var require : any = { ... } but I had to change require variable from require.d.ts file to any (declare var require: any;) too, I'm not sure if this is good hack or might cause problems in future...

Comment: I would not edit the `require.d.ts` file like you did. That weakens type-safety for the entirety of your application. What I was suggesting above also weakens type-safety because `require` has a value which is not allowed by its type but the risk of problems exists only for code that executes before RequireJS is loaded and would somehow access `require`. Small risk.

Comment: I tried reducing data-main attribute to components/main like you said but when I load the page main isn't loaded because he looks in localhost/components/main he didn't add scripts/app... this data-main attribute is giving me trouble because of the path logic it's confusing me